# Show that for an invertible matrix, the images of a set of vectors spanning the space also form a spanning set

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an invertible $n\times n$ matrix. Let $\mathcal C=\{\vec v_1,\ldots,\vec v_k\}$ be a set of vectors with $\def\span{\operatorname{span}}\span(\mathcal C)=\Bbb R^n$. Show that the set $\mathcal D=\{A\vec v_1,\ldots,A\vec v_k\}$ satisfies $\span(\mathcal D)=\Bbb R^n$.

The columns of an $n \times n$ invertible matrix are a basis for $\Bbb R^n$, so multiplying $A$ by $C$ wouldn't change the span. I'm just not sure how to "show" it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let  $T:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ the linear transformation such that $Tx:=Ax$,and
$J:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ the linear transformation such that $Jx:=A^{-1}x$, note that
J is well definded since $A$ is invertible. Note that $T\circ J=Id$ identity map of $\mathbb{R}^n$
since $T\circ J (x)=AA^{-1}x=x =J\circ T(x)$. Thus T is a linear isomorphism, so it is injective and surjective, there fore, since $span\{v_1,...,v_n\}=\mathbb{R}^n$, than
$$span\{Av_1,...,Av_n\}=span\{Tv_1,...,Tv_n\}=\mathbb{R}^n$$
Note that since T is injective, and we have $span\{v_1,...,v_n\}=\mathbb{R}^n$, so the set of vectors $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ is linearly independent (LI), so if you take
a linear combination of $a_1Tv_1+...a_nTv_n=0$ than by linearity 
$T(a_1+...+a_nv_n)=0$, and by injectivity of T, $a_1+...+a_nv_n=0$ so 
$a_1=...=a_n=0$ since  $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ are LI. Therefore, are {Tv_1,...,Tv_n} LI, and since the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $n$ we have that $span\{Tv_1,...,Tv_n\}=\mathbb{R}^n$

Answer (score 1):

$\def\span{\operatorname{span}}$In general for a linear map $f$ and any set $v_1,\ldots,v_k$ of vectors it is true that $f(\span\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\})=\span\{f(v_1),\ldots,f(v_k)\}$, by linearity ($f$ applied to a linear combination of vectors is the corresponding linear combination of their images by $f$). Applying this where $f$ is multiplication (from the left) by$~A$, and with the hypothesis that $v_1,\ldots,v_k$ span the whole space $\Bbb R^n$, one gets $A\cdot(\Bbb R^n)=\span\{Av_1,\ldots,Av_k\}$. But since left multiplication by$~A$ is surjective (even bijective), one has $A\cdot(\Bbb R^n)=\Bbb R^n$, and the desired result.